# Word array input and output and count the amount of input

Tags: c++

Input 20 words and then output the words and count how many times each word has been input.

For example if I input apple 5 times and banana 3 times and some other words so it adds upp to 20 it should output: apple=5 banana=3 kiwi=1 orange=1 etc..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string ord[21];
    for(int i=1; i<21; i++)
    {
        system("CLS");
        cout<<"Enter word number ["<<i<<"] :";
        cin>>ord[i];

    }
    for(int i=1; i<21; i++)
    {
        int count=1;
        for(int x=i+1; x<21; x++)
        {
           if(ord[x]==ord[i])
           {
             count++;
           }
        }
        cout<<ord[i]<<"="<<count<<endl;
    }
}
```

Here is my code so far it works to some extent but if you run it you can see that it says a word has been repeated then it shows the word again but this time it says it's been repeated one less time.

Comment: For this I recommend an [unordered map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), with the string as the key and the count as the data.

Comment: As for your problem with the current code, please learn how to use a debugger. With it you can step through the code line by line while watching the variables and their values. By doing that your problem should become obvious.

Answer (score 0):

LET US RUN THROUGH THE CODE

For the purposes of this example let us take 5 Words rather than 20

You can extrapolate it to 20 later

My 5 entries are

apple

apple

banana

kiwi

banana

So the first for loop(the one with i) starts with apple as ord[i]

It enters into second for loop(x)

x starts from the 2nd word

2nd word -no match count becomes 2

3nd word -no match count stays 2

4nd word -no match count stays 2

5nd word -no match count stays 2

Therefore first loop(i) output is 2 for apple

Now second fun of for loop(i) ORD is apple again!
x starts from 3 because i is 2 and x=i+1
so ord[x] are
banana
kiwi
banana
which means

3nd word -no match count stays 1

4nd word -no match count stays 1

5nd word -no match count stays 1

Therefore output is 1 for apple again

There by u get the repetition of words and improper number of words

To get over this initialize `count=0`
and let x start from 1 as well `x=1` not `x=i+1`
this will get you the correct numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    struct Word {
        string word;
        int count;
    };

    Word words[21] = {};
    int distinctWordCount = 0;
    string tempWord;
    for (int inputWordCount = 1; inputWordCount < 21; inputWordCount++) {
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Enter word number [" << inputWordCount << "] :";
        cin >> tempWord;
        int count = 0;
        for (; count < distinctWordCount; ++count) {
            if (words[count].word == tempWord) {
                words[count].count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (count == distinctWordCount) {
            words[count].word = tempWord;
            words[count].count++;
            ++distinctWordCount;
        }
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < distinctWordCount; ++count) {
        cout << words[count].word << "=" << words[count].count << endl;
    }
}
```